# Designing master page with Razor view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to create menu in **MVC3** using Razor in Visual Studio 2010.Please see attached image for an idea.
The main concern is to build Menu and Footer or how to work with `_layout.cshtml` page.
Also explain how to work with master page in **MVC3** and integration of content page with master page. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Master page with Menu]

Comment: try this article http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/01/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add your menu in header tag of _Layout.cshtml and the footer in footer tag.
Content page will be loaded in RenderBody section.To load content just give Layout path in the content page